# is it possible to change the hardware timer's time with the help of the scheduler or somehow during runtime?

Tags: operating-system, hardware, scheduler

I am studying an introductory course in operating systems and I was trying to develop a scheduler which could give a good trade off between the turn-around time of a process and the response time.

I am wondering whether or not I could change the the interval of the timer-interrupt. If I could do that, maybe I could switch between different timer intervals with respect to the number of processes that were completed in a given bigger interval of time. For example, if I completed 7 processes in the last 10 ms, switch the timer interval to 15 ms from 10 ms and therefore, switching between a responsive scheduler to a scheduler that minimizes turn-around time and hence get a better average for both.

Thank you.

Comment: Welcome to SO! Have you considered reading [How to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)? It will help you get more answers :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's split this into multiple pieces..

**Timers**

A lot of modern kernels are "tickless". What this means is (instead of having a timer generating an IRQ at a fixed frequency) the timer/s operate in "one shot" mode (one IRQ generated when the requested time elapses) and the kernel determines when the next time event needs to occur and sets the time to generate an IRQ when the next time event should occur. This approach has benefits for power management (no unnecessary IRQs bumping otherwise idle CPU/s out of power saving states) and benefits for precision (e.g. if the timer happens to run off of a 1 MHz clock, then kernel can ask timer for an IRQ with 1 microsecond granularity without having the overhead of the 1 million IRQs it'd take to obtain the same granularity with a fixed frequency). Of course there are many uses for timers (networking time-outs, sleep(), etc) so the "soonest time event" may have nothing to do with when the current task has consumed its time slice.

*Note: Modern hardware may also have timer/s running at the CPU's frequency (e.g. "TSC deadline mode" in the local APIC timer of recent 80x86 chips) where "tickless" means you can typically get "better than 1 nanosecond" precision.*

Of course for "tickless", because the kernel sets a new count for the timer (for the new "soonest" time event) each time the IRQ occurs it's extremely easy for the scheduler to use any time slice length it likes for whatever reason it likes.

**Task Switch Causes**

For a real OS, most task switches are caused because the currently running task has to wait for something (wait for data from a file or swap space, wait for a packet from network, wait for a buffer to become "not full" so it can put more data into it, wait for  data to arrive from another process via. a pipe or message, wait for a mutex to be released, etc); or because something a task was waiting for occurred. The scheduler's timer is only there to provide an upper bound for malicious CPU hogs and rare CPU bound tasks that don't need to wait for anything.

Note that (for something like a round robin scheduler using a fixed frequency timer) this causes problems. For example, if each task is given a 10 ms time slice, but a task switch has to occur after 4.321 ms because the task has to wait for something, then you don't want to waste 5.679 ms of CPU time waiting for the next timer IRQ, but you also don't want to give the next task 5.679 ms instead of the 10 ms it was supposed to get. Instead, you might configure the timer to generate an IRQ every 1 ms so that the time the next task is given can be rounded to the nearest (e.g. give the next task 9.679 ms instead of 5.679 ms and instead of 10 ms). However, this increases the overhead of handling unnecessary IRQs and hurts performance, and is one of the reasons to use "tickless" (to get rid of the unnecessary IRQs and reduce the "round to nearest" error).

**Latency In Round Robin**

For round robin schedulers "latency under load" is a crippled joke, and this has nothing to do with the timer. The problem is that a task that needs low latency has to wait for an unknown number of other tasks to have their turn. For example, if there's 200 tasks that are supposed to get up to 10 ms of CPU time each, and each of those 200 tasks actually consume an average of 5 ms of CPU time each (because most block/wait for something before their time slice ends); then a "low latency" task may have to wait for up to 1000 ms before it gets CPU time. Changing the interval of the timer from 10 ms to 5 ms might mean that those 200 tasks consume an average of 4 ms of CPU time each and the "low latency" task still has to wait for 800 ms.

*Note: In theory; one way to avoid this problem is to put a task that recently stopped waiting at the head of the "which task gets CPU time next" list, so that it gets CPU time as soon as the currently running task finishes using the CPU. In practice this allows a task to deliberately hog CPU time by waiting extremely briefly at the end of each time slice to get a whole new time slice quickly, and by using a pair of cooperating tasks malicious software can ensure no other tasks ever get any CPU time. For this reason you never put a task at the head of the "which task gets CPU time next" list.*

**Task Priorities**

What if you assigned a priority to each task, so that the scheduler knew how important a task is?

In this case, if a task needs low latency you can tell the scheduler it has high priority, and when the tasks stops waiting for something (e.g. waiting for user to press a key, waiting for a network packet to arrive, etc) the scheduler can compare the task's priority to the priority of the currently running task, realize the "low latency" task has a higher priority, and do a task switch immediately (without waiting for 200 other tasks to have their turn). In this case, latency can be "almost zero", even when the OS is under heavy load.

This does create a potential problem (high priority CPU hogs), but that problem is trivial to fix in other ways (e.g. if a high priority task takes too much CPU time without doing anything that may cause it to block/wait, either reduce its priority or terminate it as "unresponsive").

If you look at the schedulers in modern operating systems you'll find that none of them use round robin by itself. Often "round robin" is only used when 2 or more tasks have the same priority (but that's not really a good idea and I'll tell you why in the next section). Also, most operating systems provide multiple scheduling policies (e.g. maybe an OS might provide a soft real-time scheduling policy that uses "earliest deadline first", plus a "low latency" scheduling policy that uses "highest priority wins", plus a "general use" policy that might use "priority determines how many time slices", plus an "idle task" policy that might use "priority determines size of time slice"); where the scheduler gives CPU time to tasks with the best policy (e.g. if there's a real time task that wants the CPU, then idle tasks won't even be considered) and has different rules for each policy.

**Average Job Completion Times**

Let's assume that there's only one CPU; that one task wants to process a network packet and send a response and this processing will take 50 ms of CPU time; and at the same time another process wants to handle a key press from the user and the processing involved will also take 50 ms. If the scheduler switches between tasks every 1 ms then the first task will finish after 99 ms and the second task will finish after 100 ms, and the average time it takes for a task to finish its job will be 99.5 ms. However, if the scheduler doesn't switch between tasks after any amount of time (e.g. just lets the currently running task run until it finishes its job and waits for the next job to do) then the first task will finish after 50 ms and the second task will finish after 100 ms, and the average time it takes for a task to finish its job will be 75 ms (instead of 99.5 ms).

In other words, for event driven tasks (e.g. where something occurs and the task runs while handling it, then waits for the next event), a round robin scheduler (switching tasks at a fixed frequency) can make average completion times almost 50% worse than most other scheduling algorithms (e.g. "earliest start time first", "highest priority wins", ...).

**Conclusions**

a) Yes, it's entirely possible to adjust the time slice length, either by using a tickless design, or by using different values for the "IRQs per time slice" of a fixed frequency timer design.

b) For round robin schedulers, adjusting the time slice length won't help latency much (especially under load).

c) Introductory courses are an introduction - they're intended to provide information that (at some point in the future) will help you learn more advanced concepts (and are not intended to provide information that's used "as is" in practice). Round robin scheduling is one of the things that are often put in an introduction, partly because they're simple, but partly because they naturally lead to discussion/s of why they suck and how to avoid the problems (which is the beginning of most advanced concepts).